# Getting EBCDIC value of a character in C

Tags: c, character, ebcdic

I need to get the EBCDIC value of a character in C. I don't know how. Do I have to get the ASCII value first then get the EBCDIC value from there? Thanks anyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on a system that uses EBCDIC as the character encoding, you already have it:

```
char xyzzy = 'A'; // xyzzy is now 0xc1
```

If your environment is an ASCII one and you simply want the EBCDIC code point, you can just use a lookup table built from both tables, like:

[image]
[image]

A lookup tables for a system using 8-bit ASCII characters to give you the EBCDIC code points would be something like:

```
int ebcdicCodePont (unsigned char asciiVal) {
    static int lookup[] = {
        /* 0x00-07 */   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,
        /* 0x08-0f */   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,   -1,
        :
        /* 0x20-27 */ 0x40, 0x5a, 0x7f, 0x7b, 0x5b, 0x6c, 0x50, 0x7d,
        :
        /* 0x48-4f */ 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6,
        :
        /* 0x78-7f */ 0xa7, 0xa8, 0xa9,   -1, 0x45,   -1,   -1, 0x07,
    };
    if (asciiVal > 0x7f)
        return -1;
    return lookup[asciiVal];
};
```

Comment: If the system used EBCDIC, would `char` typically/always an unsigned char?

Comment: thanks @paxdiablo. could you explain to me furthermore how to use the lookup table? I don't really get how it works.