# Need <br> for as400 for a sms

Tags: sms, ibm-midrange

Is it possible to make any sort of break row in as400? And if it is, how can I do it after SMSDDD

```
   Eval      Put_Text = %Trim('Schema') + ' '  +             
    SmsDdd  +                       
    Pgr(01) + Nmn01 + ' Tid ' +     
    Nmn01 + Pgr(01) + ' Tid ' +     
    Tif01   + ' - ' + Tit01 +       
    '. ' +                          
    Nmn02 + Pgr(02) + ' Tid ' +     
    Tif02   + ' - ' + Tit02 +       
    '. ' +                          
    Nmn03 + Pgr(03) + ' Tid ' +     
    Tif03   + ' - ' + Tit03 +       
    '. ' +                          
    Nmn04 + Pgr(04) + ' Tid ' +     
    Tif04   + ' - ' + Tit04 +       
    '. ' +                          
    Nmn05 + Pgr(05) + ' Tid ' +     
    Tif05   + ' - ' + Tit05 +       
    '. ' +                          
    Nmn06 + Pgr(06) + ' Tid ' +     
    Tif06   + ' - ' + Tit06 +       
    '. ' + WrkAnv
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `Put_Text` is an EBCDIC character string variable for storing un-encoded text, then presumably inserting the ␊ charater [i.e. Line Feed, aka LF character]: …`+ SmsDdd + x'25' +`… would suffice, because that code point in that EBCDIC character encoding scheme is likely to be translated, eventually, to ASCII, as the code point 0x0A [as the matching LF character in the other character encoding scheme].

The string eventually may get *content*-specific encoding, for example to become the three characters '%0A' embedded within the encoded version of the string.  So if encoded text is to be stored in `Put_Text` as an EBCDIC string, then just insert the character string '%0A': …`+ SmsDdd + '%0A' +`… [if that is the type of content-encoding required].

Answer (score 2):

The new line character for EBCDIC is x'15', have you tried that?

```
SmsDdd  + x'15' +
```

[EBCDIC Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22033666/1367871)

Comment: There is no corresponding NL in the ASCII table at that link; that does not bode well for a known/consistent translation, per lack of an exact match. The 0x25 as LF in the EBCDIC table has an exact match to LF found in the ASCII table, as 0x0A. NB that 0x15 out of EBCDIC is typically defined to map to 0x85; with access to IBM i one can see the Hex Input to Hex Output mapping shown on the Create Conversion Table panel that is presented for the request `CRTTBL TBL(QTEMP/X) SRCFILE(*PROMPT) BASETBL(QASCII)` as verification of that effect; QASCII is defined as "EBCDIC TO ASCII TRANSLATE TABLE"